# Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-7

when I start kibana and looking in the management tab it is displaying a message

```
Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data
You'll need to index some data into Elasticsearch before you can create an index pattern
```

These are the data which are displayed in my `elasticsearch` cluster through the browser

**http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v**

```
health status index                          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana-event-log-7.9.3-000001 JBL1C589TZWBEIjhe63f1w   1   0          3            0     16.2kb         16.2kb
green  open   .apm-custom-link               nqIKOV7rR8OhzG4Y6UntSA   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .kibana_task_manager_1         3RbGcb5nTrelAfjr8cQ8Gg   1   0          6           38    150.3kb        150.3kb
green  open   .apm-agent-configuration       llIcAZAGTWanNghptfymVQ   1   0          0            0       208b           208b
green  open   .kibana_1                      tMQMj0UdRd-sCZPb631Y5g   1   0         23            9     10.4mb         10.4mb
```

I can not see `logstash` index and logstash is running under port 9600

**http://localhost:9600/**

```
{"host":"DESKTOP","version":"7.9.3","http_address":"127.0.0.1:9600","id":"b92c8d86-6159-4821-9ace-01bd5328f6af","name":"DESKTOP-MTG14LM","ephemeral_id":"4332a47b-ad63-4e02-a02e-5c233d7a3773","status":"green","snapshot":false,"pipeline":{"workers":4,"batch_size":125,"batch_delay":50},"build_date":"2020-10-16T12:25:47Z","build_sha":"d296f0087bdce367c37596241d5a1f00c9279193","build_snapshot":false}
```

logstash-sample.conf

```
input {
  file{
     type => "syslog"
     path => ["D:\Spring Boot Project\demo-gradle\another-log.log"]

}

output {

   stdout{
      codec => rubydebug
   }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

kindly support me to resolve this issue

[image]

**http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/?pretty**

```
{
  "host" : "DESKTOP",
  "version" : "7.9.3",
  "http_address" : "127.0.0.1:9600",
  "id" : "b92c8d86-6159-4821-9ace-01bd5328f6af",
  "name" : "DESKTOP",
  "ephemeral_id" : "15e38fba-b37a-4b7d-9e58-6a89e2082799",
  "status" : "green",
  "snapshot" : false,
  "pipeline" : {
    "workers" : 4,
    "batch_size" : 125,
    "batch_delay" : 50
  },
  "jvm" : {
    "threads" : {
      "count" : 30,
      "peak_count" : 32
    },
    "mem" : {
      "heap_used_percent" : 24,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 1038876672,
      "heap_max_in_bytes" : 1038876672,
      "heap_used_in_bytes" : 255060960,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 174032152,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 196833280,
      "pools" : {
        "old" : {
          "max_in_bytes" : 724828160,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 724828160,
          "used_in_bytes" : 125286040,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 724828160,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 226688920
        },
        "young" : {
          "max_in_bytes" : 279183360,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 279183360,
          "used_in_bytes" : 102941904,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 279183360,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 279183360
        },
        "survivor" : {
          "max_in_bytes" : 34865152,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 34865152,
          "used_in_bytes" : 26833016,
          "committed_in_bytes" : 34865152,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 34865144
        }
      }
    },
    "gc" : {
      "collectors" : {
        "old" : {
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 713,
          "collection_count" : 4
        },
        "young" : {
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 501,
          "collection_count" : 8
        }
      }
    },
    "uptime_in_millis" : 815971
  },
  "process" : {
    "open_file_descriptors" : -1,
    "peak_open_file_descriptors" : -1,
    "max_file_descriptors" : -1,
    "mem" : {
      "total_virtual_in_bytes" : -1
    },
    "cpu" : {
      "total_in_millis" : -1,
      "percent" : -3,
      "load_average" : null
    }
  },
  "events" : {
    "in" : 0,
    "filtered" : 0,
    "out" : 0,
    "duration_in_millis" : 0,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0
  },
  "pipelines" : {
    "main" : {
      "events" : {
        "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0,
        "out" : 0,
        "duration_in_millis" : 0,
        "in" : 0,
        "filtered" : 0
      },
      "plugins" : {
        "inputs" : [ {
          "id" : "09ae4aa0701a92b926aee6c9c0abef34b22fe75695ed89371fb40e0ce5666067",
          "name" : "file",
          "events" : {
            "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 0,
            "out" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "codecs" : [ {
          "id" : "plain_09312af1-ced8-4a87-8be0-7425fe846651",
          "name" : "plain",
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          }
        }, {
          "id" : "rubydebug_88397be3-dcbe-4553-a788-aa3d4474e141",
          "name" : "rubydebug",
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 3
          },
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          }
        }, {
          "id" : "plain_497bb40b-2eab-4852-a002-e2c7ee4d7ab3",
          "name" : "plain",
          "encode" : {
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          },
          "decode" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "writes_in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 0
          }
        } ],
        "filters" : [ ],
        "outputs" : [ {
          "id" : "e48f703a97c1645df3afa1d1b8937faffe8a408694f8a6ba5be6bb23bed53001",
          "name" : "stdout",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 33
          }
        }, {
          "id" : "ad540803354821020198353da7d7314b73309c07babecea3df737a197017449a",
          "name" : "elasticsearch",
          "events" : {
            "out" : 0,
            "in" : 0,
            "duration_in_millis" : 4
          }
        } ]
      },
      "reloads" : {
        "failures" : 0,
        "successes" : 0,
        "last_success_timestamp" : null,
        "last_error" : null,
        "last_failure_timestamp" : null
      },
      "queue" : {
        "type" : "memory",
        "events_count" : 0,
        "queue_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "max_queue_size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "hash" : "661080585b2691f01bac24b363c27f0cfc03a009fbb302424abe96cc1ae50fb5",
      "ephemeral_id" : "faf3face-77dc-455f-8632-1ff2e1ebdd7c"
    }
  },
  "reloads" : {
    "failures" : 0,
    "successes" : 0
  },
  "os" : { },
  "queue" : {
    "events_count" : 0
  }
```

**bin/logstash --log.level debug**

```
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,627][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,630][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.interval: #<LogStash::Util::TimeValue:0xa362681 @duration=10, @time_unit=:second>
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,635][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.timeout_interval: #<LogStash::Util::TimeValue:0x228ca300 @duration=10, @time_unit=:minute>
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,637][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,639][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: "certificate"
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,640][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,641][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.pipeline.details.enabled: true
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,643][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.config.enabled: true
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,644][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] node.uuid: ""
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,645][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] --------------- Logstash Settings -------------------
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,711][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Reading pipeline configurations from YAML {:location=>"D:/ELK stack/logstash/config/pipelines.yml"}
ERROR: Pipelines YAML file is empty. Location: D:/ELK stack/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
usage:
  bin/logstash -f CONFIG_PATH [-t] [-r] [] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash --modules MODULE_NAME [-M "MODULE_NAME.var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE"] [-t] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash -e CONFIG_STR [-t] [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash -i SHELL [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
  bin/logstash -V [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
  bin/logstash --help
[2020-11-16T21:59:20,755][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

**bin/logstash --log.level debug -f config/logstash-sample.conf**

```
[2020-11-16T22:11:31,227][DEBUG][filewatch.sincedbcollection][main][09ae4aa0701a92b926aee6c9c0abef34b22fe75695ed89371fb40e0ce5666067] writing sincedb (delta since last write = 15)
[2020-11-16T22:11:32,314][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2020-11-16T22:11:32,678][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:32,679][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:34,964][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2020-11-16T22:11:37,330][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2020-11-16T22:11:37,691][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:37,692][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:39,964][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
[2020-11-16T22:11:42,336][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2020-11-16T22:11:42,697][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:42,697][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2020-11-16T22:11:44,960][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][main] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the response you get when hitting `http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/?pretty` ?

Comment: http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/?pretty response updated

Comment: Ok, there are no events flowing through your pipeline... Are you sure that your config is correct? It's missing a closing `}` in your input

Comment: I am a beginner and this is the first time I have tried ELK stack. I didn't modify any config files in logstash except `logstash-sample.conf` which is mentioned in the above

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` on the command line and update your question with the output dumped during the start up?

Comment: When i run `logstash --debug` command then following error message has occurred `ERROR: Pipelines YAML file is empty. Location: D:/ELK stack/logstash/config/pipelines.yml`

Comment: Try with `--log.level debug` instead of `--debug` and of course `-f logstash-sample.conf` too

Comment: when run `bin/logstash --log.level debug -f config/logstash-sample.conf ` command then the following message is repeating many times

Comment: `bin/logstash --log.level debug -f config/logstash-sample.conf ` response is updated

Comment: I'm interested in the beginning of the log when starting up

Comment: There thousands of line of code that is why I updated the repeating part

Comment: anyway i will update all the codes

Comment: You can [gist it](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: okay here **https://gist.github.com/Benzeman97/1c81528cb1da44906ac0f826476f7ed6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file` input is reading from the end of the file. Try modifying your input like this (i.e. read from the beginning):

```
input {
  file{
     type => "syslog"
     path => ["D:/Spring Boot Project/demo-gradle/another-log.log"]
     start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

And also make sure to remove this file:

```
D:/ELK stack/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_f8a2243b9184e26704b40adf1d7ef6af
```

Comment: I have done the above changes but still, logstash couldn't find in elasticsearch data

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You **Val** for your answer. In my case, windows has been used as an OS. So the backslash which is used to route the log path should be replaced with the forward slash.

**logstash-sample.conf**

```
input {
  file{
     path => [ "D:/Spring Boot Project/demo-gradle/another-log.log" ]
     start_position => "beginning"
  }
     
}

output {
   
   stdout{
      codec => rubydebug
   }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]   
  }
}
```